# padding is invalid and cannot be removed while decrypt AES

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am facing strange issue with AES encryption and getting error while decryption.

Error while decrypt:

> padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Encrypt Method:

```
private static string Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] key)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("SharedPassword", key);

                aesAlg.Key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize/8);
                //aesAlg.IV = iv;
                aesAlg.GenerateIV();

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);


                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }
```

Decrypt Method:

```
private static string Decrypt(string token, byte[] key)
        {
            byte[] cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(token);

            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("SharedPassword", key);
                aesAlg.Key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                aesAlg.GenerateIV();

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd(); // Error here
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return plaintext;
        }
```

I have tried many work around as mention below but none of them works.
[AES decrypt fails with "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483503/aes-decrypt-fails-with-padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed)

[C#: AES error: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. Same key and everything, help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080267/c-aes-error-padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-same-key-and-everything)

I don't get what is issue with code.

Comment: Are you sure the encrypted value was encrypted using this approach to encryption? I have seen this kind of error when the value being decrypted had been encrypted a different way.

Comment: You need to save the IV from encryption and assign it on decryption